# Где найти инфу о sql server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Столкнулся с проблемой освоения SQL Server, не в плане языка, а вообще с понятиями и теорией. Может у кого-то остались старые ссылки или кто-то активный форумчанин, у которого это есть в закладках, не суть.

Прошу поделиться ссылками по следующим интересующим вопросам:

-что такое sql server как отдельный компонент;

-зачем нужен еще и sql managment studio, если уже есть sql server;

-что такое localdb, в чем его основная суть;

-экземпляр sql.

p.s как-то так, я искал статьи на хабре и тут (может уже кто задавал этот вопрос, но увы не нашел)

Comment: Душан Петкович - Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Руководство для начинающих
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19688054/

Comment: У Майкрософт есть отличные курсы по SQL Server для начинающих в [Microsft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/product-training/product-sql-server-ru#!lang=1049)

Comment: По правилам,  вопрос не должен сводится к поиску ссылок. Если вы хотите получить ответы на свои вопросы - не просите ссылки, просто спросите то,  что вас интересует.

Comment: Причем желательно оформлять разные вопросы отдельными постами :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server - это непосредственно сама система управления базами данных, которая реализует хранение и доступ к информации и т.д.

SQL Managment Studio - это консоль управления. В ней вы будите писать запросы и создавать базы.

Экземпляр SQL - на одном сервере может быть установлено несколько SQL серверов и каждый их них является отдельным экземпляром

localdb - максимально упрощенная версия сервера для разработчиков, которая включает минимальное количество компонентов необходимое для запуска SQL Server Database Engine

Comment: localdb является экземпляром sql сервера???

Comment: Точно не скажу не пользовался

Comment: @NickNick localdb - это легковесный сервер для разработки.  Он позволяет создавать новые именованные экземпляры быстро,  на лету,  без запуска инсталлера. Но видны эти экземпляры только текущему пользователю.